# form submit using ajax php

Tags: php, ajax, forms

submitting a simple contact form using ajax.

**EDITED CODE**
now trying to insert the data to database.

**html form**

```
        <form align="left" method="post" class="subscribe_form" action='subscribe.php'> 

                    Your Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" required><br>

Your E-Mail:<br>
  <input type="email" name="email" value="" required><br><br>

  Gender:
  <p>    <input name="gender" value="male" type="radio" id="male" />
      <label for="male">Male</label>

      <input name="gender" value="female" type="radio" id="female" />
      <label for="female">Female</label>
    </p>
<br>

Company Name:
<input type="text" name="cname" value="" required><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Subscribe" id="subscribe"> <span class="output_result"></span>
</form>
```

**this is my ajax code :**

```
    <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.subscribe_form').on('submit',function(){

        // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
        $('.output_result').text('Sending...'); 

        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'subscribe.php',
            dataType: "text",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                if (result == 'success'){
                    $('.output_result').text('thank you!');  
                } else {
                    $('.output_result').text('Error!');
                }
            }
        });

        // Prevents default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
        return false;   
    });
}); 
</script>
```

**subscribe.php**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "rm";

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $cname = $_POST['cname'];
    $sub_date = date("Y-m-d");



// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "insert into rmsubscribe (name, gender, email, cname, sub_date) values ('$name', '$gender','$email','$cname','$sub_date')";
$result = (mysqli_query($conn, $sql));

echo ($result) ? 'success' : 'error'; */

mysqli_close($conn);
```

this code give me  'error message'.

if i use without ajax code like this,

at form ,

without the 'class="subscribe_form"..

and in subscribe.php

```
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

instead of this

```
$result = (mysqli_query($conn, $sql));
echo ($result) ? 'success' : 'error';
```

it works fine. 'New record created successfully' data inserted into table.

Please help me on ajax code. i am not familiar with ajax. how to make this work using ajax?

Comment: can you please show your email.php file as well to see what it is returning to ajax request.

Comment: $send_email = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
      
    echo ($send_email) ? 'success' : 'error';

Comment: can you please try adding datatype to ajax request. i think ajax request when came back from email.php in unable to recognize the type of data. try adding   -  datatype: "text" to ajax request after this line data: form.serialize(),

Comment: I think ajax is expecting json as resultant data and "Success" that you are returning is not json. please check if that helps you

Comment: okay. but i i have a doubt first of all email.php is calling or not?! echo $name; echo $email; not printing any. but when i use just this "<form method="post" method="post" action='email.php'>" without the script and in email.php-- echo $name; echo $email; displaying name and email.

Comment: do you want me to add some code sample of ajax request

Comment: you can try one here - http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/aPMJF/

Comment: now, i receive message sent successfully. but not receive any mails in inbox or other folder. updated the edited code.

Comment: ok that means adding data type resolved your problem. confirm me

Comment: If you didn't got email can you please check configuration and credentials of your mail server. Try sending email from your mail server and check if its working from there. otherwise check your credentials then after these checking we can debug your code

Comment: If my answer helped your resolving your question you can mark it as answer then it may be helpful for others as well.

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. but still i don't know, really the script email.php is running or not??  i tried inserting the values into a database. here also getting success message. but data not inserted on to the db. without the ajax script, normal form submit, php insert is working fine.

Comment: added the php insert db, code . please check and help..

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add datatype to your ajax request. Actually your ajax request is expecting json and you are returning text - "Success" that is not json that's why when it gets unexpected data returned it is sending ajax response to error function. Update you code to below ajax request -

As you are returning Text as response to your ajax request so your ajax request datatype must be text as below line of code in ajax request -

```
dataType: "text"
```

**Example of your expected Ajax Request**

```
 $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'email.php',
            dataType: "text",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                if (result == 'success'){
                    $('.output_message').text('Message Sent Successfully!');  
                } else {
                    $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
                }
            }
        });

        // Prevents default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
        return false;   
    });
```